# Convert DStream to JavaDStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a function that I am calling from a scala package (DStream) that I want to convert to a JavaDStream.  I wanted to know if there is any function I could use to convert the function below to a JavaDStream to leverage in my Java application.  Or is there a similar function that spark provides that is comparable to ConstantInputDStream in the scala api library for spark?

```
//Convert DStream to a JavaDStream

  DStream refreshDstream = new  ConstantInputDStream(jssc.ssc(), emptyRDD.rdd(),scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.AnyRef()).window(new Duration(refreshInterval));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Using Constructor**

```
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = new JavaDStream<String>(dStream, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class))
```

**Option 2: Using Static method**

```
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = JavaDStream$.MODULE$.fromDStream(dStream, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class))
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know `JavaDStream` has 2 options for that:

- `JavaDStream.fromDStream()` method
- `JavaDStream` constructor

Have you tried those?